# Convert FileReader.readAsText() result string back into a file object in Java

Tags: javascript, java, file-upload, utf-8, filereader

On the website, I used FileReader.readAsText in JS for uploading a file. The result is the content of the file in text string encoded in UTF-8 format:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        resolve([key, event.target.result]);
    });
    fileReader.readAsText(value);
});
```

The request payload looks like this:

```
file: "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000..."
```

On the server-side, I need to convert the result string back into a file object in plain text in Java. I have tried the following but failed:

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // s is the input string text 
String result = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: `but failed` in what way has it failed?

Comment: That looks like a zip file, not a text file.

Comment: @Bravo By fail, I mean the result looks like unicode with very weird character. 

{"value":"PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u0000��\\�y\u0001"}

Answer (score 1):

You can `base64` encode the file and on the serverside decode it:

Client-Side:

```
fileReader.readAsDataURL(value); //instead of fileReader.readAsText(value)
```

Server-Side:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
```

Comment: What's the reason of using fileReader.readAsDataURL here? Thanks!

Comment: fileReader.readAsDataURL returns base64 encoded instead of plain text